# Do we really need "pascalprecht.translate" in input directive.?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a input directive which supports translate. 
The directive has two property input label supports translate.

My doubt is the app which need has support translate will have the **"pascalprecht.translate"** added, so any specific reason we need to add the same to directive module ?

APPLICATION:

```
 angular.module('app', ["pascalprecht.translate"]);
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
  angular.module('directive');
```

Comment: Yes. If you were to use that module in an app that doesn't include the 'pascalprecht.translate' module, it would still work. One of the points of modules is that you can include them and they should work without being aware of outside dependencies.

Comment: If you have already included it in the base module, you won't need to add it in a sub module or directive if that is what you are asking. You can easily try this out by removing the import and checking if it still works.

Comment: @DaanvanHulst: Actually its working with added to app module, but i  was suggested to add it. So thought to understand the specific reason behind the suggestion,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the comment. ( Got some more writing space here )

A reason why might be that if you copy your sub module to a different project which doesn't have the "pascalprecht.translate" included. The application won't work.

I am not sure what happens if you include something twice in the base module and in the sub module. I would hope that it will simply ignore the second include, but I will have to look this up for you.

**Edit**

Modules will only be loaded once. From the Angular website:

Modules can list other modules as their dependencies. Depending on a module implies that the required module needs to be loaded before the requiring module is loaded. In other words the configuration blocks of the required modules execute before the configuration blocks of the requiring module. The same is true for the run blocks. **Each module can only be loaded once, even if multiple other modules require it.**

Comment: the line "Modules will only be loaded once. " solved most of the problem.. :) so there may not be conflict even thought it is referred twice.... good explanation.. :)